# SELENIUM add_cookie fails sporadically with concurrence

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium chromedriver with python in linux to access to a web. I'm using cookies previously extracted from that web in order to log in that web and I set the cookies once in the web (with the same domain) and then refresh window to start doing things. I save cookies in a file and read them from it each iteration.

I use concurrence in different machines with different ips and different USER AGENTS to access different URL's of that web but I always need to be logged and that's why I use cookies.

Everything works fine with one instance and even with several concurrent instances, but from time to time I get "WebDriverException: invalid cookie domain".

My code has tons of lines of code in different files so I'm not going to paste it here. In fact, since I execute the same code in all machines I can't understand why it fails sporadically.

Anyway to understand what I do is:

loop:

```
Create chromedriver setting a random ip from a set and a random user agent from a set and get a random URL (but valid) of domain X
Add cookies (of domain X) and refresh page
Do things on the web
Close chromedriver and exit
```

In the same loop with the same cookies everythings works fine... let's say 80% of times but it fails 2 of 10 iterations.

When It fails I see that the cookie domain and the current_url are always in the same domain. I've read some "solutions" saying just adding the pair (value,name) in the cookie and many other combinations. I've tried them all and I always get the same error with the same sporadic period.

So the question is more theoretical than related with code... 
Is there any limitation in the use of the same cookie concurrently? 
Can it be something dealing with the server accepting several simultaneous logins from the same user/password? 
Maybe is something related with using different ip/useragent with the same logging credentials simultaneously? 
Maybe is something dealing with the CMS I'm accessing?

I'm accessing my own website to test it. It is a prestashop and I'm using my own credentials.

Any idea on what it may be happen? Thanks in advance.

My next try will be creating several testing accounts and use random pair of cookies (user/password) each iteration. If I stop receiving the "invalid cookie domain" error then there'd be a limitation in concurrence with the same cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I already found the problem. Since I was using a headless browser, I was getting an ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error and I had no way to check that. I was trying to set cookies for a domain in a blank page and that'w why I received the "Invalid cookie domain" error.